Is my PPL workout routine good for home workout?
Push Day:
https://hevy.com/routine/W80P5FVhSiH
Pull Day:
https://hevy.com/routine/GtmGzF2Ncua
Leg + abs Day:
https://hevy.com/routine/4DuVaP0ypLZ

Please include the text of the program in the question here, rather than only linking to it. If those links change, or you edit them program there, then the question context changes.

Overall that's really not a bad routine. A couple suggestions:

Either dump or move the plank to side plank to the legs/abs day. You've got it on the pull day, and there isn't much of a pull to it. I would look to add a different bicep exercise, you are light on those. Or a lateral raise exercise, you are also a little light on the medial deltoids.

You are very heavy on chest emphasis on the push day. I would keep all three chest exercises in the rotation, but only do two of them each time. So push #1 do decline and incline, then regular pushup/incline then regular/decline.


Few notes - I know this is equipmentless and it's really nicely put together, but I would look at getting a good quality chinup bar for a door, or a suspension trainer. Those will expand the available exercises hugely.
If you can get a gallon milk jug or two, you can fill that with water (approx 9 lbs, 4 kilos when full) or varying levels of sand to use as dumbbells and also increase the available options for exercises.
Also, don't forget rest days, and good nutrition. Without those, your gains will be slower and limited.

Thanks so much, I'm a beginner and your advice really helped me!
