Can you give me some ideas about my workout?
I cannot afford a gym or any equipment, so I'm trying to be resourceful and workout at a local park using bodyweight exercises. I wanted to ask if I could make my workout any more efficient so that it's relative to working out at a gym and make consistent gains 
Although I've asked a similar question like this, I wanted to make some adjustments to my new workout routine.
Thanks so much in advance!
Push Day:

Push ups 3 sets of 8-12 reps

Incline Push-Ups 3 sets of 8-12 reps

Decline Push-Ups 3 sets of 6-10 reps

Tricep Dips 3 sets of 8-12 reps

Shoulder Taps 3 sets of 10-15 reps


Pull Day:

Inverted Rows 3 sets of 6-10 reps

Pull ups 3 sets of 3-5 reps

Supermans 3 sets of 10-15 reps

Bodyweight Bicep Curls 3 sets of 8-12 reps

Concentration Curls 3 sets of 8-12 reps, 7 kgs


Leg + abs day:

Squats 3 sets of 15-20 reps

Lunges 3 sets of 12-15 reps

Glute Bridges 3 sets of 15-20 reps

Calf Raises 3 sets of 15-20 reps

Wall sits 3 sets of 1 min

Bicycle Crunches 3 sets of 20 reps

Planks 3 sets of 1 min

Lying Leg Raises 3 sets of 12-15 reps

Plank to Side Planks 3 sets of 6-10 reps



Can you tell us more about sets and reps? This is just a list of exercises. It might be a good workout if dosed appropriately, but if you’re doing 3 reps for one set of each exercise, it probably isn’t going to work.

What's your main goal, build muscle, lose weight, build strength?

Yup, just give me a sec

My main goal is to lose fat and gain muscle, a body recomp

Ok, I updated the sets and reps

@ThomasMarkov could I have a response, or really anybody?

@Haseen Please be patient. Also, if you haven’t received an answer here yet, you are free to revise this question using the edit button instead of posting a new question. Please allow adequate time for users to read and post answers before posting a new question.

I'm waiting for someone with more experience on calisthenics to comment on the eficiency of supermans, shoulder taps, wall sits and planks. I'd personally ditch those.

By the way why are you asking the same question multiple times? https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/is-my-ppl-workout-routine-good-for-home-workout
