Beginner and need advice
I'm a beginner and I want some advice about my equipmentless (very very tight budget) workout please!
Push Day

3 x 10-20 reps knee push ups
3 x 8-15 reps tricep dips
3 x 8-12 reps Pike Push-ups
3 x 8-12 reps Decline push ups
3 x 10-15 reps Bodyweight tricep extensions

Pull Day

3 x 8-12 reps pull ups
3 x 10-15 reps Inverted Rows
3 x 12-15 reps Reverse Snow Angels
3 x 8-12 reps Bicep Curls
3 x 12-15 reps Bodyweight Curls

Leg + Ab Day

4 x 15-20 reps squats

3 x 12-15 reps Lunges

3 x 6-10 reps pistol Squats

3 × 15-20 reps glute Bridges

4 x 15x20 reps Calf raises

3 x 1min plank

3 x 10-15 reps hanging Leg Raises

3 x 15-20 reps Bicycle Crunches

3 x 15-20 reps Russian twists


Also please let me know changes about the exercises or reps ranges if they're good or bad

What sort of answer do you expect, help with what exactly? have you used the search bar? there are other questions very similar to yours, for example https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/is-my-ppl-workout-routine-good-for-home-workout

I want some advice about if the exercises are nice, the reps ranges are good, if I'm hitting all my muscle groups.

You're new here. Questions on the site should have an objective answer; "is it nice" depends on for whom/ for what purpose. You should [edit] to give more details. But as a beginner, mostly anything will work for a year; consistency is more important.

Recommend simplifying this. As a beginner work on basic pushup in sets until you can do something like 25 in a row. Then add variety to that exercise. Same with the rest of it. If you are doing knee push-ups seems unlikely you can do pistol squats. So, basic push-ups, body squats, lunges, can you do a pull up? Maybe hang from bar and band assisted instead. Crunches, planks, wall sits. Do reps until failure/can't maintain proper form on each set. The number of reps isn't that important at this stage. Good luck!

Your schedule is pretty good but just too much puzzled and long for a beginners,you should start doing exercises from the schedule and see that if you are able to do it all with much fatigue, if you do that's pretty good, but if you not just don't feel low and make your body more tense to complete it all, little stress on body in necessary to get body fit but if you do too much, this can get you trouble for your whole lifetime if it stressed too much on your bones and muscles. I think you understand what I am saying, start slowly up to the top. Hope it helps , have a good day!!

Thanks man! I'll definitely do it
